# How to use Razor efficiently

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm trying to implement this algorith in a View page using `Razor`, but, it does not display the expected result and I don't get any compilation errors. Any suggestion please ?
**Edit :** I apologize I was not very clear, I confess. My problem is that I do not understand why `ViewBag.NbrePages` is equal to 0. However, the database had been filled.

Action();

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Rechercher(string rech, string type, int num = 1)
        {
            int nbLignesDepassees = 10 * (num - 1);

            ViewBag.Recherche = Server.HtmlEncode(rech);
            ViewBag.Type = Server.HtmlEncode(type);
            ViewBag.NumPgeCourrante = num;

            if (type == "nomAppMetier")
            {
                var appsMetiers = _db.AppsMetiers
                                                 .Where(x => SqlFunctions.PatIndex("%" + rech + "%", x.nomApplication) > 0)
                                                 .OrderBy(x => x.nomApplication)
                                                 .Skip(nbLignesDepassees)
                                                 .Take(10);
                ViewBag.NbrePages = (int)(appsMetiers.Count() / 10) ;
                return View("RechercheAppsMetiers",appsMetiers);

            }

            if (type == "nomPoste")
            {
                var postes = _db.Postes
                                        .Where(x => SqlFunctions.PatIndex("%" + rech + "%", x.nomPoste) > 0)
                                        .OrderBy(x => x.nomPoste)
                                        .Skip(nbLignesDepassees)
                                        .Take(10);
                ViewBag.NbrePages = (int)(postes.Count() / 10);
                return View("RecherchePostes", postes);
            }

            return HttpNotFound();
        }
```

View();

```
<ul>
@{
        for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.NbrePages; i++)
        {
            if(i==1 || i==2 || i==3){
                <li class="disabled"><a href="#">&maquo;</a></li>
            }else{
                <li><a href="#">&laquo;</a></li>
            }

            if (i == ViewBag.NumPgeCourrante)
            {
                <li class="active"><a href="#">@i <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            }
            else
            {
                <li><a href="#">@i </a></li>
            }

            if(i==ViewBag.NbrePages || i==ViewBag.NbrePages-1 || i==ViewBag.NbrePages-2){
                <li class="disabled"><a href="#">&raquo;</a></li>
            }else{
                <li><a href="#">&raquo;</a></li>
            }
        }
}
</ul>
```

Thanks a lot !

Comment: What result do you expect, and what gets displayed? Also, there is a lot of logic in this view. Typically this should go in the controller, in order to create a model that you pass to a strongly-typed view. This makes code that is easier to understand.

Comment: Nothing gets displayed, I expected displaying a list of Integer elements. Wow, then have any suggestion how to make this code work making the call of a controller+view instead of only one view?

Comment: If nothing gets displayed, it could be that `ViewBag.NbrePges` is zero. In this case `<ul></ul>` would get rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NbrePages` will be either 0 or 1 (if you have more that 10 records) due to `Take(10)` and using integer division:

```
 ViewBag.NbrePages = (int)(appsMetiers.Count() / 10) ;
```

So most likely you get less that 10 items in `appsMetiers`.

Suggestion to improve source based on original misspelling of the variable in CSHTM:

Using good names or strongly typed model would help to avoid spelling like  `NbrePges` in `for` condition in original post:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.NbrePages; i++)
```

CSHTML files are not compiled till run-time access, so no compile errors. Since `ViewBag` allows any property to be used you are not getting any intellisense warning either.

Instead of `ViewBag` consider some strongly typed model or at least put strongly typed object for paging into `ViewBag`:

```
 class PagingState 
 { 
      public int NumberOfPages { get;set;}
      public int CurrentPage { get;set;}
 }
```

and in view:

```
 var pageingState = (PagingState)(ViewBag.Paging);
 for(int I = 0; i < pageingState.NumberOfPages; i++)...
```

Comment: I've edited my post, sorry for not being explicit from the outset.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than having so much logic in the view, consider the following:

A model

```
public class PagesModel
{
    public int NumberOfPages { get; set; }

    public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
}
```

A helper method in a class

```
public static class Helpers
{
    public static bool GetClassNames(int page, int totalPages, int currentPage)
    {
        var classNames = new List<string>();

        var isWithinFirstOrLastThree = page <= 2 || page >= (totalPages - 2);

        if (isWithinFirstOrLastThree)
        {
            classNames.Add("disabled");
        }
        if (page == currentPage)
        {
            classNames.Add("active");
        }

        return string.Join(" ", classNames.ToArray());
    }
}
```

And then your view could be as simple as

```
@model PagesModel

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.NumberOfPages; i++)
{
    <li class="@Helpers.GetClassNames(i, Model.NumberOfPages, Model.CurrentPage)">
        <a href="#">&maquo;</a>
        @i
    </li>
}
```

This doesn't exactly match what you are trying to achieve, but I hope that it is helpful nonetheless.

Comment: Thank you very much Richard this had inspired me. But, I can't pass it to the view like model, because it uses another one AppMetierModel

Comment: Why not create change `AppMetierModel` to include all the information your view needs, or create a new model class, that contains a property of type `AppMetierModel`?

Comment: I'm thinking about that. That will respect much more the rules of MVC but needs more time to code and to define dependencies.